# SocketIO hangs at 250 concurrent connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

The issue is basically that socketio is hanging at 250 concurrent. Whether via `node app.js –nouse-idle-notification –max-old-space-size=8192 ulimit -n 2048 --expose-gc`  oder `pm2`, it has the same effect.

I'm running centOS7. I have 30GB of ram and it's a proper VPS.

I have tested locally and on production server, with pm2 and without, with cluster and without. It always stops at 252/256 and says no more resources. I'm only connecting, nothing else is sent.

Here's the most basic example that I've used.

```
import express from "express"
const app = express();
import http from "http"
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io"
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I have a SocketIO running on SSL-domain, with reverse proxy, along with cluster nodes. Server is apache.

The problem is simple. Once the server reaches 256 connections, it shuts down, which is weird.

The logs show `reason transport close` using `pm2 logs > yourlogFile.txt &`

I'm running a stress-test using `npx artillery run my-scenario.yml`, the `yml` file is the default from `socket.io` docs, but set it to `websocket` only as transports.

`app.js` has a redis for the cluster adapter. I'm using `admin-ui` to monitor the connection. It shows `6 servers created` then once it reaches 256 connections (1 connection via `admin-ui` and 255 connections via `artillery` stress test), it shuts down.

```
import {createServer} from "http";
const httpServer = createServer(app);
import {Server} from "socket.io";
import {createAdapter} from "@socket.io/redis-adapter";
import {setupWorker} from "@socket.io/sticky";
import { createClient } from "redis";
const pubClient = createClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {...})
```

Apache's config is straightforward:

```
SSLEngine on
      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPass "/websocket/socket" balancer://nodes_ws/
      ProxyPassReverse "/websocket/socket" balancer://nodes_ws/
      ProxyTimeout 3

Header add Set-Cookie "BlazocketServer=sticky.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
      <Proxy "balancer://nodes_polling">
        BalancerMember "https://localhost:3000" route=app01
        BalancerMember "https://localhost:3001" route=app02
        BalancerMember "https://localhost:3002" route=app03
        ProxySet stickysession=BlazocketServer
      </Proxy>

      <Proxy "balancer://nodes_ws">
          BalancerMember "ws://localhost:3000" route=app01
          BalancerMember "ws://localhost:3001" route=app02
          BalancerMember "ws://localhost:3002" route=app03
          ProxySet stickysession=BlazocketServer
      </Proxy>

      RewriteEngine On
      #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
      #RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]


      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
      RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://nodes_ws/$1 [P,L]

      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
      RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://nodes_polling/$1 [P,L]
```

the scenario is simple

```
config:
  target: "myurl"
  socketio:
      path: "mypath"
      transports: ["websocket"]
      
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 10
  engines:
   socketio-v3: {}

scenarios:
  - name: My sample scenario
    engine: socketio-v3
    flow:
      # wait for the WebSocket upgrade (optional)
      - think: 1

      # basic emit
      - emit:
          channel: "hello"
          data: "world"

      # emit an object
      - emit:
          channel: "hello"
          data:
            id: 42
            status: "in progress"
            tags:
              - "tag1"
              - "tag2"


      # emit with acknowledgement
      - emit:
          channel: "ping"
        acknowledge:
          match:
            value: "pong"

      # do nothing for 30 seconds then disconnect
      - think: 30
```

After checking manually to connect in a for-loop with timed interval, i'm getting failed: `failed: Insufficient resources`

Comment: Https normally operates on port 443 not on port 80 which is http. You should check you apache config for a VirtualHost with port 443 an enable ssl there. Remove the ssl config from the VirtualHost on port 80.

Comment: Have you restarted apache after you have edited the configs? If not do so and check apaches log files.

Comment: I am not sure but I think its problem is with reverse proxy config, have you configured your server as suggested here [reverse proxy](https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/) & [load balancer](https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/)

Comment: I did, the config is also included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is Apache and its `MaxClients` setting, which by default is 256.

This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/481881/what-to-do-after-hitting-the-dreaded-256-max-connections-apache-limit) on serverfault details comprehensively how to approach changing the setting.

To understand how threads on Apache translates to maximum clients that can be served , this [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) and this [discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/796968/apache-2-4-max-concurrent-users-limit) are good references.

Answer (score -1):

Try multiplexing to reduce socket connections